# How to automatically add items to an array in an object in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have an object in vue called answers:

```
            answers: {
            'type': 'Senior',
            'weight': 'Normal',
            'contains': []
        },
```

If I want to add another item in the object I use the following code:

```
Vue.set(this.answers, key, answer);
```

Now I can't figure out how to add items to the contains array. Whenever I use the above code it adds 1 item in contains but when I try to add another it just replaces the other one. Does anyone know how to add more items to contains in Vue?

Comment: `Vue.set(this.answers, 'contains', [...this.answers.contains, answer])`

Comment: The contains in this.answers.contains is dynamically added through a parameter in a Vue method called key as you can see in my code. Do you know how I can dynamically add this parameter to the this.answers.contains bit? so .contains should be replaced with the parameter key.

Comment: And also, do you happen to know how to delete a specific item in the object? So basically the reverse of Vue.set. I've tried your answer but instead of Vue.set I did Vue.delete, but that just deleted the whole object instead of the single instance.